# Angular build takes too long

Tags: angular, angularbuild

When I want to build my Angular project It takes more than 50 minutes. I searched a lot but did not find any solution...

I used the following command and did not work:

```
ng build --configuration production --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --build-optimizer
```

I Increase node memory limit for the build but does not work:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production
```

**NOTE:** I removed the `allowedCommonJsDependencies` in angular.json but does not affect it.

my angualr.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "remotejobs": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "rj",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/remotejobs",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/844294.txt",
              "src/assets",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf",
              "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer",
              "lodash.clonedeep",
              "@assets/packages/ck-editor/build/ckeditor.js",
              "flat"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/toastr.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/styles/ng-select.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles.scss",
                "inject": true
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "300kb",
                  "maximumError": "600kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "remotejobs:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "remotejobs:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "remotejobs:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "remotejobs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "transloco:optimize": "transloco-optimize dist/remotejobs/assets/i18n",
    "postbuild": "gulp COMPRESS_JS_FILE",
    "start:dev": "ng serve --port=4200",
    "start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 4200 -c-1 dist/remotejobs",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration=development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@abacritt/angularx-social-login": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^6.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.0.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^11.0.0",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "^4.3.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.7.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^12.0.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.5",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^16.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^11.1.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^16.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^17.0.2",
    "persian-utilities": "^1.1.1",
    "pretty-print-json": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.2",
    "@ngneat/transloco-optimize": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^4.9.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.4",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.0.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*":[
        "assets/*"
      ],
      "@app/*": [
        "app/*"
      ],
      "@app/core/*": [
        "app/core/*"
      ],
      "@app/shared/*": [
        "app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@app/auth/*": [
        "app/auth/*"
      ],
      "@app/modules/*": [
        "app/modules/*"
      ],
      "@app/employer-panel/*": [
        "app/employer-panel/*"
      ],
      "@app/job-seeker-panel/*": [
        "app/job-seeker-panel/*"
      ],
      "@app/resume/*": [
        "app/resume/*"
      ],
      "@app/website/*": [
        "app/website/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: can you also share your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: @Corey Sutton - I updated my question and add tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the base64 font of 'Calibri' in one of my components.scss file. like the following:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Calibri";
font-weight: 100 900;
font-style: normal italic;
src: url(data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAEAAAAVAQAABABQRFNJR68djRoABUaIAAAbWEVCRFQxOa4XAAQb6AAAT5xFQkxDfDVvAAAEa4QAABXgR0RFRgAmBGYABIFkAAAAHkdQT1....
}
```

I removed base64 and use the font file directly.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks, my friend. I had used another font like the above .... you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

This could use some additional info, so I will give an answer but will also ask some follow up questions.

How large is your project?
Is your tsconfig.json optimized?
What is the load time of your external dependencies? One of those could be slowing the entire process to a halt.
Are you lazy loading your modules if you have several?

One thing that stands out that will certainly help is adding Build Parallelization.

You can enable parallelization in Angular CLI to speed up the build process. To do this, open your angular.json file and add the parallel option under the options section for the build target:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "parallel": true, // Add this line to enable parallelization
      // Other options...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have 220 components and used lazy loading for load modules.I add `tsconfig.json` to my question.

Comment: Hm. Your tsconfig looks good so I do not think it's that!

Comment: Is your npm properly configured? You can test the response of the npm registry with npm ping